# Do skills from Strong Attack Tree have any effect on other skill trees?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm going for a light attack build.

In the description of skills Rend and Sunder Armor from the Strong Attack tree they say nothing about the skill helping only heavy attacks.

Do I get those bonuses when using light attacks too?

Answer (score 1):

Rend is actually an active skill (move), as opposed to a passive bonus, and consequently is not applied during Light Attacks.

Sunder Armor debuffs damage resistance (armor) on enemies you hit with Heavy Attacks.
It does not apply when you attack with Light Attacks, but the debuff remains on the enemy and will affect **all** damage sources afterwards (including bombs, crossbow, physics, etc).

> Sunder Armor: Reduces enemy damage resistance by (5-25)%

Comment: You can incorporate my answer to your, we each complete a part of the question

Answer (score 1):

Sunder armor is actually applying a debuff on your target when you hit them.

It IS cumulative with fast attacks, you just have to engage with an heavy blow before sticking him to death with your death dance.

Comment: How do you know?